# How to change string literals in Eclipse (from a VIM user)

Tags: vim, eclipse

Assume that the cursor is at the top of the following file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>    
    <string name="app_name">Hello World</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="menu_settings">Settings</string>
</resources>
```

How would one copy the last `string` element and change its values to:

```
    <string name="edit_message">Enter a message</string>
```

In VIM I would `/men<Enter>Yp` to get to the line and copy it below, then simply `ciw` and `cit` to change the values.

In Eclipse I found `Ctrl-J men` to get to the `menu_settings` text, but now how does one copy the line below and then `ciw` and `cit` for the values?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to install [Vrapper](http://vrapper.sourceforge.net/home/) or some other Vim plugin for Eclipse. That's what most Vimmers who have to work in Eclipse (or any other IDE) do.

Basically, it allows you to perform the action in your example exactly the same way with the exact same keystrokes. Obviously, Vrapper and the other plugins are not Vim so you'll necessarily find limitations but all the basics are there. I recommed it.

---

Without Vrapper, I can do <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to copy the line (like `yy` but without the newline), <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> to open a new line (like `o`) and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> to paste. After that you'll have to do a lot of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Arrows</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> to select and change values because Eclipse doesn't have the concept of text-objects.

Comment: Thank you! I have tried all manners of VIM plugins but I think that I will be best off learning how Eclipse works, rather than trying to make Eclipse VIM. I think that you've worded my frustration perfectly with this: "Eclipse doesn't have the concept of text-objects".

Comment: I use Vim for everything *except* AS3 for which I use Eclipse with the Flash Builder plugin. Vrapper is not perfect but I'd feel a lot more miserable if it didn't exist. Your comment touches a very important matter: when "switching" to another tool, the most futile thing is to not aknowledge it as "another" tool and try to make it conform to your false expectations. This works for people going IDE -> Vim and, obviously for people going the other way.

Comment: Switching? Apostasy! Merely summing up the 'competition'. All married men so occasionally! Thanks, Romani, your posts are always insightful and helpful. Have a peaceful weekend!